# building cardano-node and cardano-cli on nix

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm following the instructions here:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/getting-started/building-the-node-using-nix.md/

But I'm not sure how to get it to compile the 1.35.3 versions. The commands at `nix build .#cardano-node -o cardano-node-build` and `nix build .#cardano-cli -o cardano-cli-build ./cardano-cli-build/bin/cardano-cli` build versions 1.31.0 after completion

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by updating my path variable to point to the new builds. In `/.bashrc`, i appended

`export PATH="$HOME/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-node-build/bin/:$PATH"`